infinity product topology and box topology
I'm currently learning about introductory topology, where we are studying the differences between the box topology and the product topology on a non-finite product space.
I came across a comment stating that typically:
$T_\mathcal{prod} \subsetneq T_\mathcal{box}$
I've been trying to find an example or construct one where this inequality holds as an equality, where:
$T_\mathcal{prod} = T_\mathcal{box}$
Could you please provide some guidance on how to construct such an example? Also, could you provide an example where $T_\mathcal{prod} = T_\mathcal{box}$ actually occurs?

The instances where the box topology and the product topology on $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ are equal can be classified rather easily: they are equal if and only if either ${j\in I,:, X_j\text{ is not an indiscrete topology}}$ is finite or $\prod_{i\in I}X_i=\varnothing$.

by {$j\in I : X_j $ is not an indiscrete topology} you mean that there is an index s.t $X_j$ dont have the indiscrete topology or that all of them

He means (and said) that this set is finite.

Let $\{X_j\}_{j \in J}$ be a family of spaces. Let $Y = \prod_{j \in J} X_j$.
Recall that the box topology $T_b$ on $Y$ has basis elements of the form $\prod_{j \in J} U_j$, where $U_j \subseteq X_j$ is open for each $j \in J$.
Recall that the product topology $T_p$ on $Y$ has basis elements of the form $\prod_{j \in J} U_j$, where $U_j \subseteq X_j$ is open for each $j \in J$, and there is a further requirement that $U_j \ne X_j$ for finitely many $j \in J$.
Obviously, $T_p \subseteq T_b$ (i.e., the box topology is finer than the product topology), because every basis element of the product topology satisfies the condition that $U_j \subseteq X_j$ is open for each factor $j \in J$.
The topologies coincide when $T_b \subseteq T_p$. A trivial case where this happens is if $X_j = \emptyset$ for some $j \in J$, in which case $Y = \emptyset$ (and all topologies on the empty set trivially coincide). Assuming that all factor spaces are non-empty, $T_b \subseteq T_p$ when, roughly speaking, the factor spaces are sufficiently small. Let $T_j$ be the topology on $X_j$. I claim the following:

Suppose $Y \ne \emptyset$. Then $T_b \subseteq T_p$ if and only if $T_j \ne \{\emptyset, X_j\}$ for finitely many $j \in J$.

To prove the forward direction, suppose that there is some infinite collection $I \subseteq J$ such that $T_i \ne \{\emptyset, X_i\}$ for each $i \in I$. Consider the basis element of the box topology $B = \prod_{j \in J} U_j$, where $U_j = X_j$ if $j \notin I$, and $U_j$ is some arbitrary element in $T_j - \{\emptyset, X_j\} \ne \emptyset$ if $j \in I$. The set $B$ is clearly not open in the product topology because $U_j \ne X_j$ for all $j$ in the infinite collection $I$.
To prove the reverse direction, let $B = \prod_{j \in J} U_j$ be a non-empty basis element of $T_b$; by definition, $U_j \in T_j$ for all $j \in J$. Let $I \subseteq J$ be the collection of indices $i$ such that $T_i \ne \{\emptyset, X_i\}$; by hypothesis, $I$ is finite. For all $j \in J - I$, we clearly have $U_j = X_j$ (otherwise $B = \emptyset$). Let $I' \subseteq I$ be the collection of indices $i$ such that $U_i \ne X_i$. Then we see that $U_j \ne X_j$ only for $j$ in the finite set $I'$, showing that $B \in T_p$, as desired.

Thanks! this proof made it very clear
